# Referencing resources in module

Tags: android, module, android-studio

I've create a module at Android Studio. In module code, I want to show a dialog which uses a layout defined in the module. When I reference layout like     **net.gwtr.module.R.layout.my_dialog_layout**, I get this exception;

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "net.gwtr.module.R$layout" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/net.gwtr.moduletest-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/net.gwtr.moduletest-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
```

I think the reason is that resources are merged when you add a module to project. It did not create different resource ids for the module package name. So i cannot reach to resources from module package.

How can I reference resources of module in module code?

Edit1:
I reference resource like this;

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.my_dialog_layout);
dialog.show();
```

Edit2:
**I found a way but i don't want to use this every time when I reference resource.**

I can reach resources when I get resource id with this;

```
context.getResources().getIdentifier("my_dialog_layout", "layout", context.getPackageName())
```

Comment: How are you referencing R? Show your code please.

Comment: Reproduced you problem: buildToolsVersion '20.0.0' Gradle 0.12.2 Android Studio 0.8.6. Also tested it with other resources - R class not found.

Comment: @ferar1988 thanks for sharing your solution , did you find another more convenient  way to do this ?

Comment: There is a long treatment of these questions here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62694206/android-studio-project-that-builds-for-both-wear-os-and-normal-app-but-shares-s/

Answer (score 4):

In your gradle file from your module.

Are you put compile your other module?

```
compile project(':othermodule')
```

Comment: yes, i can reach any module classes. But module cannot reach its own resources.

Comment: Have you compiled it as apklib?

Comment: No, i just create a new module inside the project.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, resources from libraries are merged into your application (so basically there's a global namespace under R; this is why you have to choose resource names in modules with a little care, e.g. use a prefix, to prevent accidental mix-up with resources from other modules).

Within the defining library module, and your application module by virtue of the resource merging, you should just be able to refer to *R.layout.my_dialog_layout* (android studio should auto-complete). I've a similar situation working fine in my project (*@jimpanzer*: I tried under same versions as you, with compileSdkVersion = 16 and 20).

Some suggestions:

- make sure there are no import statements of R anywhere. As far as I can see you shouldn't need any, if you either address library resources from your application module, or from the same library module.
- clean your project and rebuild, perhaps even android studio caches. In the old days, sometimes R.java would get screwed up.

Answer (score 2):

I'm converting a legacy project to android studio and managed to get the package names mixed up in the module. Although the R file was generated it was in the wrong package.

In the module check the resource to id mapping file

build->generated/source->debug->(app package)->R

or

build->generated/source->release->(app package)->R

The package of this file should match the import of R e.g. in your activity

Answer (score 2):

I had to add the package name for the resource, e.g. instead of `R.drawable.icon`, I needed `com.example.brand.module_name.R.drawable.icon`

Answer (score 1):

import `net.gwtr.module.R.*` and access the layout via `getResources()` like you had before