# Android Studio project that builds for both Wear OS and normal app, but shares source files

Tags: android-studio, gradle, module, wear-os, android-tv

I have a very small Android app that I have ported to Wear OS.  It works OK.
But now I have two separate projects, whose source files are 99.5% identical.
How can I put both versions in one project, so only one copy of each common source file is needed?

(For instance, the Manifest file needs to be tailored -- at least for the `uses-feature android.hardware.type.watch`, and one source file needs to be different -- menus in the Android app have to be handled differently on the Wear app.  One resource was tailored for the small screen size.  Everything else is identical.)

I tried making two modules in the one project, one "app" the other "wear".  But since modules seem to correspond to directories, this doesn't directly address the problem of shared source files.

I played with "Build Configurations" -- but I see nothing about paths there.
I spent some time with "Build Types", which deal with "dependencies", but I couldn't sort out how to make one module look into the other module's directory tree for, say a res/ directory.

What is the right way to resolve this?

Comment: I have implemented a work-around using soft links in Linux.  But that makes the project non-portable.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sharing files between Android mobile and wear modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36117365/sharing-files-between-android-mobile-and-wear-modules)

Comment: Well, it's one direction.  I think the idea there is to have a "common" module that builds a library file that is then included in the other modules.  Building a library seems a little excessive for this very small project -- I had in mind just to arrange to change the include paths for the java files.

I played with it a bit: first off, in AS 4.0, the `compile` directive has to be changed to `implementation`.  The build.gradle file of the shared module has to specify `apply plugin: 'com.android.library'`.  Next...  the shared module needs a manifest.  I'm stuck there.

Comment: The manifest of the shared library module can literally be a one-liner: `<manifest package="com.example.common" />`. It just can't be the same package name as your (non-library) app modules.

Comment: I made some headway with your help @string, but I'm stuck again.
Now I want a resource file in the `wear/` module to override those in the `shared/` module. 
But it seems that resource files placed in `wear/src/main/res/` are not being found: the corresponding symbol doesn't appear in the `R` package.

Generally I have no way to know where the IDE is looking for resources, let alone how to configure it.  Can somebody point me to the proper documentation?

Comment: Android Studio can be a bit wonky in finding resources, but if it's having trouble, look at what `.R` path you have in your `include`. Should match the package name of the module that the source file is in. FWIW, this is nothing to do with Wear, it's standard library-module stuff; have you read the docs at https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library#Considerations ?

Comment: Well, I read that doc now.  Not sure I understand everything...especially how the line
"...each library has its own R class, named according to the library's package name".
The way I thought this worked was, everything was under the same package name -- this is a very small project -- is this a mistake though?

Comment: I don't have an explicit `include` (you mean a Java `import`?).  I just use, like `R.string.name`.  OK I see that is because from the source file of the package, that is accessed relative to the package name, like `org.goldang.stringtuner.R.string.name`.
SO, does this mean that each module in the project has to have a distinct name, if the android R mechanism is to be used?

That would mean that the app, the wear OS app, and the "shared" module would each have its own distinct package name.  This is not what I had envisioned -- but if it must be...

Comment: OK I tried re-naming the Wear OS module's package as `org.goldang.stringtuner_wear`, changing its source path to 
    `wear/src/main/java/org/goldang/stringtuner_wear/`
and the resource path to
    `wear/src/main/res/`
But inside of source of the package `org.goldang.stringtuner_wear`, the variable `org.goldang.stringtuner_wear.R` is unknown.
Is there some Gradle eye-of-newt I've missed?

Comment: I commented out the offending source lines so the thing would build, and looked at the APK file.  It contained only the "shared" resources -- nothing from `wear/src/main/res`.
This must be a Gradle thing.  How can it be configured to recognize an overriding resource in a module?

Answer (score 2):

## namespaces

It is important to keep the namespaces of source and resources of different modules distinct. Exactly how this is done is arbitrary.

In a simple case of an Android app and a Wear OS app that share code and resources, I adopted the following structure:

```
org.domain.theproject
    <shared code and resources under this>
    org.domain.theproject.app
        <Android app code and resources>
    org.domain.theproject.wear
        <Wear OS app code and resources>
```

The namespace of each module is defined in the Gradle build file.

If everything is set up properly, resources for dependent modules are merged with those of the library module, so that a reference such as

```
android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
```

could refer to a resource of that name defined in the library module, or one defined in the

(I don't know what happens when there is a resource name conflict.)

## directory structure

I have been using this structure in projects where an Android app and a Wear OS app
share a common library:

```
TheProject/
    AppModule/
        src/main/
            java/org/domain/theproject/
                app/
                    <Android app source files>
            res/
                layout/
                < etc. >
    SharedModule/
        src/main/
            java/org/domain/theproject/
                <shared library source files>
            res/
                layout/
                <etc. >
    WearModule/
        src/main/
            java/org/domain/theproject/
                wear/
                    <Wear OS app source files>
            res/
                layout/
                < etc. >
```

## manifest

- Each module must have its own manifest file, `AndroidManifest.xml`, under

  src/main/

Only those for apps are copied into the final APK file, though.

- Library modules have a very simple manifest: two lines suffice, something like:

  `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`
  `<manifest package="org.domain.theproject"/>`

This serves to indicate the package under which compiled resources of that library can be accessed.

- Manifests for modules for Wear OS or Android apps will be more elaborate -- the usual structure with elements

  `<application>` and `<activity>`
- Names of packages within the manifest prefixed with a dot '.' are relative to the `package` attribute of the `<manifest>` tag.  Other packages, especially those within a shared library module, may be accessed by a full explicit package path.

The above package structure can be neatly realized by a manifest structured like this:

```
<manifest 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="org.domain.theproject.app">
    <!-- ... -->
    <application >
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <!-- ... -->
```

The activity name will then be understood to be `org.domain.theproject.app.MainActivity`.

Also, the `package` attribute provides a package for the `R` resource in Java code: in the above case, the default `R` is really `org.domain.theproject.R`.

- Resources referred to within the manifest ... are in a kind of flat namespace merged from the resource names of the library resources and the dependent module resources. It is very easy for a conflict to arise.

## Gradle build file

Library `build.gradle` files must begin with

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
```

App `build.gradle` files must begin with

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
```

Besides the usual module dependencies, the `build.gradle` of app modules must list dependencies on the library modules they use.  For instance, if an app module is dependent on library module "shared", then its `build.gradle` file must indicate that dependency in its dependencies section, like:

```
dependencies {
    implementation project(':shared')
    //...
}
```

Of course, `build.gradle` files for Wear OS apps will also have dependencies for Wear OS, and Android apps will have dependencies for, say, AndroidX.  But if a library they depend on has the same external dependencies, linking conflicts may occur.  See "external library dependencies" below.

Note that the `applicationId` property, as in

```
android {
 defaultConfig {
        applicationId "org.domain.theproject"
        }}
```

does not necessarily reflect the Java class structure (although that is a good convention).
It is rather the identifier for the app (or package?) that the OS uses to identify the app.

## shortcomings of Android Studio

Android Studio squirrels information away willy-nilly, and regularly gets confused as to what it put where.  All sorts of perplexing behavior results and much time is wasted.
(This being just one general area of bug infestations in the program.)

It happens horribly often that things stop making sense, and

```
Build -> "Clean Project"
```

does not suffice, and nor does that, plus

```
File -> "Sync Project with Gradle Files".
```

Sometimes one must

```
File -> "Invalidate Caches/Restart"
```

And the fact is, sometimes one must turn AS off, go in with a console, and manually delete the hidden directories etc.  I will not go into that here.

In doing the sorts of things described here, you will surely run into such issues,
especially where it comes to the R interface between resources and Java code.
I don't have any clear way to identify when these problems are happening,
or which measure to take.  You just have to develop a feeling for it.

## Java source

### classes

Obvious to those experienced with Java:
the package names in Java files must reflect the directory structure;
within AS, that means relative to the module's directory

```
src/main/java/
```

Library module classes are merged with those of the dependent modules
at that level -- class names can be imported across modules in the usual
Java way. So to effect the structure above, a Java file

If the Gradle config and manifest are configured properly, classes from the library module can be accessed from dependent modules as though the directories beneath the modules' `src/main/java` directory had been merged.

### resources

The package that holds the automatically-generated resource package `R` is
defined by the `<manifest>` tag's `package` attribute in the module's manifest file.
But it is possible to refer explicitly to resources defined within other packages.

For instance, within the code of the dependent app package

```
org.domain.theproject.app,
```

the unqualified symbol `R` refers to the generated resource package

```
org.domain.theproject.app.R
```

The resources of the library package

```
org.domain.theproject
```

may be referenced explicitly in the same code via

```
org.domain.theproject.R
```

### the R package in shared libraries

An annoyance of converting conventional app code to a shared library: the elements in `R` are not static -- so they can't be used in `switch` statements.  It's not a big deal to convert them to `if...else`, but if you have a lot of them...

## resource XML

TODO -- how to access resources of a library module from within resources of a dependent module?

## minimum SDK versions

It is possible for the minimum SDK version of the library modules
to be lower than that of the dependent app modules, but not the other way around.

Thus, the minimum SDK version for a Wear OS module could be the lowest possible for Wear apps (23),
while that of the Android app module in the same project could be the lowest possible for AndroidX (14),
provided the shared library module has its minimum SDK version set to 14.

The target SDK versions of all modules should match.
(I guess -- haven't checked.)

## external library dependencies

I have managed in simple examples to avoid using Jetifier, by manually resolving dependency conflicts between dependent modules and library modules.  This way, APK file can turn out much smaller. It requires some thought, and experimentation.

This is all accomplished int the Gradle build file's `dependencies` block.  I think the principle is: starting with the independent library modules,
load required dependencies with the property

```
implementation
```

but in dependent modules that require the same dependencies, load them with the property

```
compileOnly
```

So if the library module and the app module need the external library

```
'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'
```

the library will have listed in its `dependencies`

```
implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'
```

while the app module will have

```
compileOnly 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'
```

(If both are listed as `implementation`, then "Duplicate class" errors occur;
if the independent class is missing the `compileOnly`, errors saying a package
that "does not exist" will occur.)

Further, it is also possible to tailor just what is linked in the `implementation` directive by using `exclude` properties.